# Importing React and ReactDOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When importing react and reactDOM I have always seen:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Can I name React and ReactDOM something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### React

For `React`, you **must** `import React from 'react'`. You need to import the default, and you need to name it `React`. This is because anytime you write JSX code like `<MyComponent />` or `<App />`, this JSX code is transpiled and uses `React.createElement()`. So, you need to have access to the `React` object as it is named.

#### ReactDOM

For `ReactDOM`, however, you are probably mostly concerned with the DOM-related methods that are part of the default export, methods like `render()` or `hydrate()`. Because that's what you'll probably be using, you can name your import module anything you want. So, you could do something like this:

```
import FooBar from 'react-dom'
FooBar.render(someElement)
```

This *does* work, but the standard convention is to call the imported module `ReactDOM`, as that would make your code more understandable to anyone else looking at it.

---

Additional resources:

- [ES6 syntax and usage of import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)
- [Babel tranform of JSX requires React](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx)
- [ReactDOM documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html)

Comment: Just an update: React 17 and some older specified major versions now include a new JSX transform that does not require this explicit React import. See https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html